# replace and looping character in java netbeans?

Tags: java, loops, replace

i have code like this :

```
private void submitBTNActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String inp = inputText.getText();
    String res=inp.replaceAll(",", "x \n");
    outputText.setText(res);
}
```

replace , is success but i don't know how to looping that.
for example

```
input in textbox inputText:
12,45,54 x 7
33,43x5

execute value in textbox outputText:
12x
45x
54x7
33x
43x5
```

i want execute value is

```
12x7
45x7
54x7
33x5
43x5
```

i hope someone can help me, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant at all but try it :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String inp = "12,45,54 x 7";
    String [] inpSplited1 = inp.split("x");//split into two parts at "x" 
    String [] inpSplited2 = inpSplited1[0].split(",");//split first element in array after each ","
    for(String str :inpSplited2 ){
        System.out.println(str + "x"+inpSplited1[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Uzochi, after i try the code is success in terminal output but in textbox output just last number 54x7

Comment: where do you set the text? in the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

it has to be something like this

```
private void submitBTNActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
  String inp = inputText.getText();
  String [] inpSplited1 = inp.split("x"); 
  String [] inpSplited2 = inpSplited1[0].split(",");
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  for(String str :inpSplited2 ){
      sb.append(str).append("x").append(inpSplited1[1]).append("\n");
  }
  outputText.setText(sb);
}
```